# What is this pattern

Tags: javascript

I was working on a util and while validating a user we need to check if it has a pattern like this or not

```
if (!/^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*$/.test(username)) {
    errors.username = 'Username must have alphanumeric characters only.';
}
```

What is `!/^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*$/`?

Comment: It's a regular expression (a regexp): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Use https://regexr.com/ to test your reg exps

Comment: Note that this regular expression allows empty usernames

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer

The "pattern" is a regular expression. The regular expression there ensures that the username only contains letters and numbers ([a-zA-Z0-9]), dash or hyphen (`-`) and underscore (`_`) characters (-_). The `^` indicates the start and `$` indicates the end. The `*` is a wildcard to match one or more of the tokens (`[a-zA-Z0-9-_]`). This essentially allows me to create usernames like:

1. `_-`
2. `--_`
3. `-`
4. username-
5. username-something-else
6. user_name

But not:

1. user@
2. user.
3. /user

You may wish to use something like `/^([a-zA-Z0-9]){1}([a-zA-Z0-9-_])*$/` to ensure that the first character is a letter or number and then allow for `-` and `_`.

### Learn More

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions
2. https://regexr.com/5ts1i